# Почему не работает функция foreach c PDO?

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Имеется простой код

```
# Get array of containers
$arr = file(www.'/names.db');

$checkQ = 'SELECT `name` FROM ' . $tb['table'] . ' WHERE `name`=?';
$check = $dbh->prepare($checkQ);

foreach($arr as $value) {
    echo '<p>' . $value.' :: ';

    $check->execute(['%' . $value . '%']);
    echo $check->rowCount();
}
```

который по идее должен выводить список строк из файла (в котором одно имя на строчку) а рядышком указывать, сколько совпадений нашлось по базе данных.
Но он не работает. Имя выводит правильно, но вот у каждого имени красуется 0, и только у последнего - 1 (и он действительно есть в базе)
если убрать foreach, и вместо $value подставлять какие-либо значения - всё работает.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @Nickolay, даю наводку: посмотрите на сформированный SQL-запрос.

Comment: в том, что в конце каждой строчки стоит символ перевода \n, и только у последней его нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать немного другой синтаксис. А в функцию `execute()` передавать массив `array`.

```
$checkQ = 'SELECT `name` FROM ' . $tb['table'] . ' WHERE `name`=%:name% ';

$check = $dbh->prepare($checkQ);

foreach($arr as $value) {
    echo '<p>' . $value.' :: ';

    $check->execute(array('name'=>$value));
    echo $check->rowCount();
}
```